# Spring Integration JMS Inbound Channel Adapter not polling at specified fixed-rate

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I've defined a JMS Inbound Channel Adapter as following in Spring Integration 3.0.1.RELEASE:

```
<int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inChannel" phase="1000"
                                 destination-name="jmsQueue" extract-payload="true"
                                 connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

But multiple messages are consumed from the JMS broker at random non-reliable distances, which can go from several seconds to several minutes between each message being consumed. I've tried with `fixed-delay` instead of `fixed-rate` but it has the same behavior.

Which other factor could be making the poll operations be performed at different times, and how could I achieve reliable polling times?

**EDIT:**

I've confined the application to a single default poller, with a single JMS Inbound Channel Adapter (although there are some Message Driven Channel Adapters), and it's still having the same behaviour. I've twitched the wait times to `fixed-delay` of 3000 and a `receive-timeout` of 5000.

I've started the application with some messages on the JMS queue to be picked up, and the logs show entries like this, switching the thread of the task-scheduler after some callback operations as shown below:

```
2016-09-23 18:48:25,592 | DEBUG | ask-scheduler-1 | ework.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate | Executing callback on JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:v10033215-56491-1474666967074-0:18:1,started=true} 
2016-09-23 18:48:25,630 | DEBUG | ask-scheduler-1 | ion.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter | Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false' 
2016-09-23 18:48:28,639 | DEBUG | ask-scheduler-1 | ework.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate | Executing callback on JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:v10033215-56491-1474666967074-0:19:1,started=true} 
2016-09-23 18:48:28,643 | DEBUG | ask-scheduler-1 | ion.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter | Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false' 
2016-09-23 18:48:31,651 | DEBUG | ask-scheduler-3 | ework.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate | Executing callback on JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:v10033215-56491-1474666967074-0:20:1,started=true} 
2016-09-23 18:48:31,657 | DEBUG | ask-scheduler-3 | ion.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter | Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false' 
2016-09-23 18:48:34,666 | DEBUG | ask-scheduler-1 | ework.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate | Executing callback on JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:v10033215-56491-1474666967074-0:21:1,started=true} 
2016-09-23 18:48:34,670 | DEBUG | ask-scheduler-1 | ion.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter | Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
```

And then, 10 minutes later:

```
2016-09-23 18:58:10,032 | DEBUG | ask-scheduler-8 | ework.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate | Executing callback on JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:v10033215-56491-1474666967074-0:212:1,started=true}
2016-09-23 18:58:10,091 | DEBUG | ask-scheduler-8 | ion.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter | Poll resulted in Message:
```

And the message is consumed.

I've took multiple dumps, and could find only one instance of a task-executor thread on RUNNING state:

```
"task-scheduler-4" prio=6 tid=0x000000001074f800 nid=0x4364 runnable [0x000000001d4fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedOutputStream.flush(TcpBufferedOutputStream.java:115)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.oneway(TcpTransport.java:167)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.oneway(InactivityMonitor.java:237)
    - locked <0x00000007dc803080> (a java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.oneway(TransportFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:40)
    - locked <0x00000007dc8031f8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.oneway(ResponseCorrelator.java:60)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doAsyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1225)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.asyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1219)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.doClose(ActiveMQSession.java:590)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.close(ActiveMQSession.java:581)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.closeSession(JmsUtils.java:108)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:497)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receiveSelected(JmsTemplate.java:761)
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsDestinationPollingSource.doReceiveJmsMessage(JmsDestinationPollingSource.java:118)
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsDestinationPollingSource.receive(JmsDestinationPollingSource.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:184)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:143)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:141)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:273)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:268)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

All other thread dumps show that all threads for the task-scheduler are either on WAITING or TIMED_WAITING as the following (including the thread on the previous dump after it finished). This dumps from 30 seconds after the last one:

```
"task-scheduler-4" prio=6 tid=0x00000000118d3800 nid=0x4abc waiting on condition [0x000000000f8bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007838d74d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1085)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"task-scheduler-3" prio=6 tid=0x00000000118d4800 nid=0x4f14 waiting on condition [0x000000001ba0f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000787c10210> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of pollers in your application, you could be suffering from thread starvation; the [default task scheduler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler) only has 10 threads; you can increase the count.

Pollers polling from `QueueChannel`s block for 1 second by default.

Generally, turning on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` will help resolving issues such as this.

Taking a thread dump and looking at the task scheduler thread activity should also help.

Comment: I've edited the post with some logs and thread dumps, still couldn't sort it out thou :/

Comment: It's hard to say, clearly the poller is interacting with ActiveMQ - closing the session. I don't know activemq internals and why that might take a long time. I could imagine sporadic timing if you have HUGE messages and/or a poor network. Next step I would take if debugging this would be to look at a network trace with WireShark or similar.

Comment: Sorry, I was out for vacations during last week. I can't use WireShark as I'm on a controlled environment with a limited toolbox :/
One thing I'd look it's that, while I'm specying `receive-timeout = 5000`, the poll operation last apparently quite less (some polls are reported as 'false' almost instantly), while the operation that does report a message being received takes more time. Isn't it supposed to wait 5 seconds between the start of the callback operation and the result being reported as 'false'?

Comment: Yes, but that's up to your JMS provider to honor that api - see the JavaDoc for `Consumer.receive(long timeout)`. If that exits early it's the provider's issue. If the messages are huge, the provider library might block when it sees there's a message on the way, but, again, that's the provider library. I fear you won't be able to track this down without a network monitor. Can you not run tcpdump locally?